# I want to use the logitech dll within visual basic, but i cant reference it?

Tags: vba, logitech-gaming-software

Just trying to create my own applet with my Logitech g510 keyboard. To allow me to connect with my emails etc. Whenever i try tor reference the .dll file I get this following message.

[image]

From location: C:\Program Files\Logitech Gaming Software\SDK\LCD\x64

How can I import this correctly?

Comment: Have you done what the error message says (make sure it is valid COM component)?

Answer (score 0):

As @GSerg suggested, this is likely not a COM component DLL, so it cannot be referenced this way. Instead, you use the "Public Declare" statement to import functions from the DLL so you can call them from your VBA code. You have the documentation for the DLL, right?...